# AttributeError: module 'torch.utils' has no attribute 'tensorboard'

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, tensorboard

I tried to use tensorboard in torch.utils, but it says "module 'torch.utils' has no attribute 'tensorboard'".
My torch version is "1.6.0+cu101"

```
PS C:\Users\kelekelekle> python
Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 01:54:44) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>> print(torch.__version__)
1.6.0+cu101
>>> writer = torch.utils.tensorboard.SummaryWriter()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'torch.utils' has no attribute 'tensorboard'
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to install `tensorboard` via:

```
pip install tensorboard
```

(or a-like). Given that is done, you should import `tensorboard` module from `torch.utils` package:

```
from torch.utils import tensorboard

tensorboard.SummaryWriter("foo")
```

Or you can import `SummaryWriter` directly:

```
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter

SummaryWriter("bar")
```